# How to properly use PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, sql-injection

I'm trying to work with PDO to make my scripts more secure. I have a demo and so I set the variable to this `$STH->bindParam(':ip', $ip);`, then call it like this

```
$DATA = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (ip) VALUES (':ip')");
```

The problem is for some reason its not entering into the database. Here's a my full code:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "users";
$user = "root";
$pass = "root";


try{
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);    
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}



$ip = generateRandomString().sha1($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']).generateRandomString();


$STH->bindParam(':ip', $ip);

$DATA = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (ip) VALUES (':ip')");
$DATA->execute();

?>
```

And yes I understand that that's not how to get the IP an so fourth, I'm just playing around with PDO and MYSQL.

Comment: try it in this order (and without quotes on `:ip`): `$DATA = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (ip) VALUES (:ip)");
$DATA->bindParam(':ip', $ip); $DATA->execute();`

Comment: Didn't seem to work @aldanux

Comment: and what's the different with my code and from echo_me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to binfd parameter after the query not before

```
 $DATA = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (ip) VALUES ( :ip )");
 $DATA->bindValue(':ip', $ip , PDO::PARAM_STR); // if ip column is string
 $DATA->execute();
```

[some ref](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

Comment: It still works without `PDO::PARAM_STR`, is `PDO::PARAM_STR` a more secure way? Also great and simple answer

Comment: I'm not sure if you read over the question in the last comment. It works without `PDO::PARAM_STR`, is `PDO::PARAM_STR` needed>

Comment: @user302975 when you remove that parameter, you are leaving it up to PDO to determine the data type'

Comment: not needed , but it Explicit data type for it will not be inserted as other type.

Comment: like that you specify the data type .

Comment: Just one more thing. If i wanted to do multiple variables, would i do two instances of `bindValue`?

Comment: yes you do two bindValue, just look to that link i provided. there is example there.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind parameters only after preparing the query, otherwise what are you binding?

```
$ip= generateRandomString().sha1($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']).generateRandomString();
$stmt= $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (ip) VALUES (:ip)");
$stmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip);
$stmt->execute();
```

Unlike `bindValue`,  `bindParam` allows you to bind before or after the variable is initialize because it uses the variable reference not the value, so you are allowed to put create `$ip` after binding.

```
$stmt= $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (ip) VALUES (:ip)");
$stmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip);
$ip= generateRandomString().sha1($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']).generateRandomString();
$stmt->execute();
```

both would work in this case.

Comment: When I check in the DB I get `:ip` as a result, not the actual generated string...

Comment: @user302975 thats because you had quotes around it